# How to assign a three.js ShaderMaterial to multiple objects loaded from Blender

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, blender

I’m working on a project where I need to load a scene that contains a lot of objects.
The scene is exported from Blender using the three.js exporter.

Some of the objects in the scene require a custom shader (ShaderMaterial).
My problem is that I’m not sure on how I could select a specific set of objects, loop through them and assign to them the custom shader I created. The only thing they have in common is their material in Blender.

I have several leads:

- Is it possible to select three.js objects based on their material?
- Is it possible to add a sort of common Id in Blender to be able to select the objects easily in three.js? Some of the objects are unrelated so I can’t just group them.
- Is it possible to edit the exported .json file and modify the material created by Blender with a ShaderMaterial instead?
- Or is there simply a better way to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You could use `object.traverse( child => \* Check for some material identifier here, like child.material.color.r == 1 if the material is pure red in color *\ ? child.material = myShaderMaterial : false)`, but this is hard to say. We dont know how your object looks, or how to identify similar materials (do they all use the same color? The same map?).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess I can simply check for the `material.name` then.